# Are people 'made for each other'?

Tags: relationships

If Eve was made by Yahweh to be a partner for Adam, are we able to then accurately know that there really is someone out there 'made for you'? And if so, does this partnership (even if not called a 'marriage') continue in Heaven? And could this person actually be someone you never get to meet during your time in this life (or someone other than the person you marry while here), perhaps because of the consequences/effects of original sin from the start?

Comment: I don't know, but I am pretty sure Adam did say to Eve, "You're the only woman in the world for me!"

Comment: ...and then she rolled her eyes, and the rest is history...Lol! Thanks Narnian :o)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is one that I frequently encounter especially from teenagers. And usually I find that the real question they want answered is 'Is there someone God created to be my soul mate for life?' Of course neither I nor anyone else except God himself can answer that question. However I will be happy to tell you what Scriptures say about the subject.

Mar 10:6 through 9  King James Version

> 6  But from the beginning of the creation God made them male and female.
>
> 7  For this cause shall a man leave his father and mother, and cleave to his wife;
>
> 8  And they twain shall be one flesh: so then they are no more twain, but one flesh.
>
> 9  What therefore God hath joined together, let not man put asunder.

So what point is Jesus making with that statement? He is telling us that God's intent was that when two people marry it is God's intention for that marriage to last a lifetime. Therefore it is incumbent upon us to select our mate very carefully.

The reason that selection is so important is that as we see in verses 7 and 8 That mate whom you select and you become one and the same, from that time on what one does effects the other whether it be how to spend money or who gets up in the middle of the night when the baby cries.

So does God create a specific person for you to the exclusion of all others? I cannot imagine that that would be the case since God gave us free will, and with that free will we are free to choose any partner we want, and if God only gave one person to choose from where would our free will be?

I in fact believe that for some people, it is God's intent that those persons mot have a mate and that they dedicate themselves to his service. The Apostle Paul for instance said:

1st Corinthians 7:1 and 2  KJV

> Now concerning the things whereof ye wrote unto me: It is good for a man not to touch a woman.
>
> 2  Nevertheless, to avoid fornication, let every man have his own wife, and let every woman have her own husband.

And:

1st Corinthians 7:6 through 9  KJV

> 6  But I speak this by permission, and not of commandment.
>
> 7  For I would that all men were even as I myself. But every man hath his proper gift of God, one after this manner, and another after that.
>
> 8  I say therefore to the unmarried and widows, It is good for them if they abide even as I.
>
> 9  But if they cannot contain, let them marry: for it is better to marry than to burn.

Here Paul is saying that it will please God if you decide to remain single and remain totally dedicated to his service, but he is also aware that it is very difficult to control your emotions, and that it is far better to marry than to go against God's commandments.

This precept is the reason for Priest and Nuns not to marry and join their chosen profession of dedication to service of the LORD.

Finally; Let's examine why god created Eve.

Genesis 2:18  KJV

> And the LORD God said, It is not good that the man should be alone; I will make him an help meet for him.

So we learn from this Scripture that God created  woman so that man would not be alone. But not just to be a companion as we see in the second part of this verse she was to specifically be his helper, or in other words they were intended to work together to secure the blessings of God whether they be tangible or intangible.

These are some things you need to keep in mind when making a decision who to marry, and as a Christian one very important thing is to find someone who will work together with you to secure God's blessings. That is the reason for the following Scripture;

2nd Corinthians 6:14  KJV

> Be ye not unequally yoked together with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with unrighteousness? and what communion hath light with darkness?

Comment: Thank you greatly Cecil! It just occurred to me one day, if A & E had not eaten the fruit, then all of their descendents would have 'fallen into place', genealogically speaking, without sin to mess it all up! And since God didn't give A & E a selection to choose from, I assume free will in that case wasn't necessary. And may not have been necessary for any of us, at least as far as a partner/helper is concerned, because without sin we would always be paired rightly, like A & E. And since we were created to live forever, I'd guess the partnering was meant to last. One day we'll know! Amen :o)